# After passing ctree nosetests I failed after updating .bashrc to include openmp

Tags: gcc, environment-variables, icc

I was able to pass the ctree nosetests before I downloaded the intel compiler for the openmp libraries. After downloading the compiler and changing bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/llvm-omp/bin/:$PATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/llvm-omp/include:/opt/intel/composerxe/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/llvm-omp/include:/opt/intel/composerxe/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/llvm-omp/lib:/opt/intel/composerxe/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/llvm-omp/lib:/opt/intel/composerxe/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/composerxe/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now, however, I fail the nosetests with this error:

```
/opt/intel/composerxe/include/math.h:29:3: error: "This Intel <math.h> is for use with only
  the Intel compilers!"
```

Comment: I've fixed tags. the question does not relate to OpenMP at all but is about ICC environment but when used with other compilers (GCC presumably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
/usr/include:
```

and

```
/usr/lib:
```

respectively before all the rest of the paths in your environment variables, so it uses your system headers before it finds the intel ones.

Comment: Ok thanks that works when I added those to the front of each respective path.

Comment: It's not a good advice because it effectively disables ICC environment, i.e. just do not add `/opt/intel/composerxe/include` to C*PATH